# Time Spinner OverwriteMode JAVA

Tags: java, swing

i have used this code i found on the internet and i would just like to know why only the "seconds" part of the spinner can be overwritten using Keyboard inputs when highlighted. Time format used is HH:mm:ss.

If "hours" or "minutes" part is highlighted and I press numbers on the numpad, nothing happens. Am i missing something here?

Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;
import javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.Format;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * <code>DateSpinner</code> is a spinner that is specialized in displaying or editing a a date or time.
 * <p/>
 * To change the value, you can use {@link #setValue(Object)} and pass in a Date. To get the
 * Date, using {@link #getValue()}.
 */
public class DateSpinner extends JSpinner {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public DefaultFormatter _formatter;
    public DateEditor _timeEditor;
    public DateFormat _format;

    /**
     * Creates a date spinner using "hh:mm:ss" as the format string.
     */
    public DateSpinner() {
        this("hh:mm:ss");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a date spinner using the specified format string.
     *
     * @param format the format string as defined in {@link java.text.SimpleDateFormat}.
     */
    public DateSpinner(String format) {
        this(format, new Date());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a date spinner using the specified format string and an initial value.
     *
     * @param format the format string as defined in {@link java.text.SimpleDateFormat}.
     * @param date   initial value
     */
    public DateSpinner(String format, Date date) {
        super(new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        setFormat(format);

        customizeSpinner();
    }

    private void customizeDateEditor() {
        JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter formatter = _timeEditor.getTextField().getFormatter();
        if (formatter instanceof DefaultFormatter) {
            _formatter = (DefaultFormatter) formatter;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The formatter is not an instance of DefaultFormatter.");
        }

        if (formatter instanceof InternationalFormatter) {
            Format f = ((InternationalFormatter) formatter).getFormat();
            if (f instanceof DateFormat) {
                _format = ((DateFormat) f);
            }
        }

        if (_format == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The format is not an instance of SimpleDateFormat.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the date format string used by this DateSpinner. Please note, this method call
     * will recreate the DateEditor used by DateSpinner.
     *
     * @param format
     */
    public void setFormat(String format) {
        _timeEditor = createDateEditor(format);
        customizeDateEditor();
        setEditor(_timeEditor);
    }

    /**
     * Customizes the spinner.
     */
    protected void customizeSpinner() {
        setLenient(false);
        setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
        setAllowsInvalid(false);
        setOverwriteMode(true);
        //SpinnerWheelSupport.installMouseWheelSupport(this);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the DateEditor.
     *
     * @param format
     * @return the DateEditor.
     */
    protected DateEditor createDateEditor(String format) {
        return new DateEditor(this, format);
    }

    /**
     * Sets when edits are published back to the
     * <code>JFormattedTextField</code>. If true, <code>commitEdit</code>
     * is invoked after every valid edit (any time the text is edited). On
     * the other hand, if this is false than the <code>DefaultFormatter</code>
     * does not publish edits back to the <code>JFormattedTextField</code>.
     * As such, the only time the value of the <code>JFormattedTextField</code>
     * will change is when <code>commitEdit</code> is invoked on
     * <code>JFormattedTextField</code>, typically when enter is pressed
     * or focus leaves the <code>JFormattedTextField</code>.
     *
     * @param commit Used to indicate when edits are committed back to the
     *               JTextComponent
     */
    public void setCommitsOnValidEdit(boolean commit) {
        _formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(commit);
    }

    /**
     * Returns when edits are published back to the
     * <code>JFormattedTextField</code>.
     *
     * @return true if edits are committed after every valid edit
     */
    public boolean getCommitsOnValidEdit() {
        return _formatter.getCommitsOnValidEdit();
    }

    /**
     * Configures the behavior when inserting characters. If
     * <code>overwriteMode</code> is true (the default), new characters
     * overwrite existing characters in the model.
     *
     * @param overwriteMode Indicates if overwrite or overstrike mode is used
     */
    public void setOverwriteMode(boolean overwriteMode) {
        _formatter.setOverwriteMode(overwriteMode);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the behavior when inserting characters.
     *
     * @return true if newly inserted characters overwrite existing characters
     */
    public boolean getOverwriteMode() {
        return _formatter.getOverwriteMode();
    }

    /**
     * Sets whether or not the value being edited is allowed to be invalid
     * for a length of time (that is, <code>stringToValue</code> throws
     * a <code>ParseException</code>).
     * It is often convenient to allow the user to temporarily input an
     * invalid value.
     *
     * @param allowsInvalid Used to indicate if the edited value must always
     *                      be valid
     */
    public void setAllowsInvalid(boolean allowsInvalid) {
        _formatter.setAllowsInvalid(allowsInvalid);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the value being edited is allowed to be invalid
     * for a length of time.
     *
     * @return false if the edited value must always be valid
     */
    public boolean getAllowsInvalid() {
        return _formatter.getAllowsInvalid();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the time zone for the calendar of this DateFormat object.
     *
     * @param zone the given new time zone.
     */
    public void setTimeZone(TimeZone zone) {
        _format.setTimeZone(zone);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the time zone.
     *
     * @return the time zone associated with the calendar of DateFormat.
     */
    public TimeZone getTimeZone() {
        return _format.getTimeZone();
    }

    /**
     * Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient.  With
     * lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that
     * do not precisely match this object's format.  With strict parsing,
     * inputs must match this object's format.
     *
     * @param lenient when true, parsing is lenient
     * @see java.util.Calendar#setLenient
     */
    public void setLenient(boolean lenient) {
        _format.setLenient(lenient);
    }

    /**
     * Tell whether date/time parsing is to be lenient.
     */
    public boolean isLenient() {
        return _format.isLenient();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you press arrow keys? This is a spinner and not a textfield. Besides - I'm sure the answer is found in the DateEditor class. Please add a reference to the page where you found the classes.

Comment: it does work if i use arrow keys.
i found it here:
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jidesoft/jide-oss/2.0.4/jide-oss-2.0.4-sources.jar!/com/jidesoft/spinner/DateSpinner.java?format=ok

Answer (score 0):

When stared from the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), the [example](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jidesoft/jide-oss/2.0.4/jide-oss-2.0.4-sources.jar!/com/jidesoft/spinner/DateSpinner.java?format=ok) works correctly using any of the arrow keys, number keys or numeric keypad keys.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new DateSpinner());
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: problem still happens.
try to highlight the HH part of the time spinner and input numbers using the numeric keypad keys, nothing happens, but if you try to highlight the ss part of the time spinner and input using the numeric keypad keys, the existing numbers are overwritten

Comment: @joLo: I can reproduce the modal behavior you describe. Once the hour or minute field is selected, either left- or right-arrow restores keypad entry. I should be possible to change the key bindings if desired: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html